# How to change default 'username' in django-graphql-jwt

Tags: python, django, graphql

query `tokenAuth` in django-graphql-jwt requires two fields: `username` and `password`, but I want to use `phone` or `email` instead of `username`. Do I have to change source code of library?

Comment: I haven't got the chance to look at the source code yet, but the authors of the 3rd party packages for Django are usually using User abstraction provided by Django - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are subclassing Django's `AbstractBaseUser` to create your custom `User` model, then you will have to provide `USERNAME_FIELD` and set it to whatever you want to use to log in, for instance, `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`. You can read about the USERNAME_FIELD [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/). Then you can do something like:

```
mutation {
  tokenAuth(email: "youremail@gmail.com", password: "password") {
    token
  }
}
```

Make sure the `is_active` field of the user you are trying to log in is set to `TRUE` since Django's default authentication class checks that it is set as so when authenticating (unless you have overridden this behavior with your custom authentication method). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[django-graphql-auth](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) uses django-graphql-jwt to authenticate and have a default login mutation that works with username, email or a secondary email.

It works with the default user model or a custom one.

Example from the [docs](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#obtainjsonwebtoken)

```sh
mutation {
  tokenAuth(
    # username or email
    email: "skywalker@email.com"
    password: "123456super"
  ) {
    success,
    errors,
    token,
    refreshToken,
    unarchiving,
    user {
      id,
      username
    }
  }
}
```